# foot bones move separately from the rest of the mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

My problem https://ctrlv.cz/8XI1

[image]

My foot bones moves separately from the rest of the mesh.
How can i fix this?

Comment: The foot bone should be parented to the lower leg bone (dotted line indicates it is parented to the head).

Comment: Foot bone is parented to the root bone, not the head.

Comment: https://ctrlv.cz/pX4x It's just that my foot mesh doesn't follow with the rest. I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lF6ryktrht0 and i checked if i have everything the same and i have. So i don't get it, where's the problem?

Comment: it shouldn't move like this. https://ctrlv.cz/DSFO 
It should follow the bottom leg join, but still remained in flat position without rotation.

Comment: @NikolasMarkovič could you provide your .blend file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you